# jQuery - How to traverse to the first child of the same parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to traverse to the first child of the same parent div starting from an element at a given index.

I have "word" divs wrapping around "letter" divs.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="twelve columns">
    <div class="word">
      <div class="character">
        <div class="number">
          4
        </div>
        <div class="options">
          GHI
        </div>
        <div class="letter">H</div>

      </div>
      <div class="character">
        <div class="number">
          3
        </div>
        <div class="options">
          DEF
        </div>
        <div class="letter">E</div>

      </div>
      <div class="character">
        <div class="number">
          5
        </div>
        <div class="options">
          JKL
        </div>
        <div class="letter">L</div>

      </div>
      <div class="character">
        <div class="number">
          5
        </div>
        <div class="options">
          JKL
        </div>
        <div class="letter">L</div>

      </div>
      <div class="character">
        <div class="number">
          6
        </div>
        <div class="options">
          MNO
        </div>
        <div class="letter">O</div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="word">
      <div class="character">
        <div class="number">
          4
        </div>
        <div class="options">
          GHI
        </div>
        <div class="letter">I</div>

      </div>
      <div class="character">
        <div class="number">
          7
        </div>
        <div class="options">
          PQRS
        </div>
        <div class="letter">S</div>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="character">
      <div class="number">
        4
      </div>
      <div class="options">
        GHI
      </div>
      <div class="letter"></div>
      <div class="select">
        <select class="word-options">
          <option value="">Select a word</option>
          <option value="IT">IT</option>
        </select>

      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="character">
      <div class="number">
        8
      </div>
      <div class="options">
        TUV
      </div>
      <div class="letter"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="character">
      <div class="number">
        7
      </div>
      <div class="options">
        PQRS
      </div>
      <div class="letter"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="character">
      <div class="number">
        3
      </div>
      <div class="options">
        DEF
      </div>
      <div class="letter"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="character">
      <div class="number">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="options">
        ABC
      </div>
      <div class="letter"></div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var decoder = {};
decoder.firstEmptyIndexPrevious;

var findPrevStart = function(startIndex){

//if startIndex is not defined, set it to index of current cursor position
if (!startIndex){
    startIndex = $('div.select').parents('div.character').first().index('div.character');
}

//index of first letter in word before the position of the start index. should return 5 in this example
decoder.firstEmptyIndexPrevious = $('div.character:lt(' + startIndex + ')').last().siblings('div.word div.character').first().index();

//decoder.firstEmptyIndexPrevious = $('div.character:lt(' + startIndex + ')').last().parent().children().first().index();

console.log('startIndex = ' + startIndex);
console.log('decoder.firstEmptyIndexPrevious = ' + decoder.firstEmptyIndexPrevious);
}

 $(document).ready(function() {
   findPrevStart();
 });
```

Basically, in decoder.firstEmptyIndexPrevious, I want to get the index of the first letter of the word immediately before where this select element appears (it will move through the DOM dynamically like a cursor). startIndex is returning 7 as expected, but decoder.firstEmptyIndexPrevious is returning 0, no matter where it runs from. This happens both in the active line and the commented-out line with a slightly different approach. It should return 5 in this example. Not sure what's wrong.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrengy/h2DZG/1/

Comment: Can you simplify your example or describe exactly what you want? It is confusing when you talk with numbers and not actually ask what you want.

Comment: @Vega I asked for what I was looking to achieve in an earlier paragraph, but I just moved the order of the text around to put that last.

Comment: `index()` with no argument returns the index of the element within its parent. The selections are finding the `.character` DIV with options `GHI`, which is the first child of its `.word` parent, so the index is 0.

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that :-

- your `.character` elements are not all in the same `.word` container
- `.index()` finds the index of an element amongst its siblings in the DOM, not within a jQuery collection.

Also, you appear to need mechanisms for `findPrevStart()` to work with and without a `startIndex` passed to it.

Here's the code :

```
var findPrevStart = function(startIndex) {
    var $divChar;

    if (typeof startIndex !== 'undefined') {
        $divChar = $('div.select').closest('.columns').find('div.character')[startIndex];
    }
    else {
        //if startIndex is not defined, set it to index of current cursor position
        $divChar = $('div.select').parents('div.character').first();
        startIndex = $divChar.index('div.character');
    }

    //index of first letter in word before the position of the start index. Should return 5 in this example
    var char = $divChar.prevAll('.word').eq(0).find('div.character').get(0);
    var chars = $divChar.closest('.columns').find('div.character').get();
    decoder.firstEmptyIndexPrevious = $.inArray(char, chars);

    console.log('startIndex = ' + startIndex);
    console.log('decoder.firstEmptyIndexPrevious = ' + decoder.firstEmptyIndexPrevious);
};
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2DZG/6/)**